# Is there a way to set the coverage band details of a layer on geoserver using python?

Tags: python, geoserver-rest-pythom

Is there a way of twitching the minRange and maxRange values of a layer on geoserver using some python library?

[image]

I have tried using two libraries to access and list all the layers that I have on geoserver, but I have not found any functions that can access these values.

```
from geoserver.catalog import Catalog
from owslib.wms import WebMapService


cat = Catalog(service_url="http://localhost/geoserver/rest", username='username', password='password')
wms = WebMapService(url='http://localhost/geoserver/workspace/wms',
                    version='1.3.0',
                    username='username',
                    password='password')

layers = list(wms.contents)

that_layer = cat.get_layer(layers[0])

res = that_layer.resource
```

Comment: You'll need to do a GET request on the coverage then edit the XML to POST it back.

Comment: could you please provide some more details?